# Different popover for editing and non editing text field

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Ok, sorry if the title is a little off. Hope I explain it better here. What I want to do is have a popover (iPad app) that will do different things based on the state of a UITextField. So if the user is typing in that text field and then taps the popover button, the popover appears and if the user taps something in that popover it will get added to that text field (think something like adding often used text). In this situation the popover will only disappear when the text field finishes editing.

However if the user taps the popover button when the text field is not editing then that list of items still appears but now it should disappear if the user taps outside the popover.

I hear something about pass-through views, but I'm not certain that is what I need.
Does anybody know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passthrought views are views outside the popover that don't cause it to dismiss automatically. When you want to dismiss the popover from your code when the textfield has finished editing call `[myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]`.

For adding text blocks into the textfield I think delegation is the right thing to do. You set the your main view as the delegate of the conten view of the popover and each time a text block in the popover is selected you tell the delegate to add this block to the textfields text.

When you want to prevent the popover from dismissing while the textfield is being edited you should implement the `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` methode `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:`.